# How to implement the SimpleMiddleware?

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am struggling getting MiddleWare to work. I put this in my `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'portal.middleware.SimpleMiddleware'
]
```

and I implemented this class in `portal/middleware/MiddleWare.py`:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

But when running, I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: @BearBrown 1.10.2

Comment: Your entry in the settings `'portal.middleware.SimpleMiddleware'` suggests a `SimpleMiddleware` class in portal/middleware.py`, which does not match your filename `portal/middleware/MiddleWare.py`. In Python, you usually avoid CamelCase for module names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing a new-style middleware, you should use `MIDDLEWARE` instead of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.

You also need to make sure that your entry in the settings matches the location of the middleware. The entry `'portal.middleware.SimpleMiddleware'` suggests a `SimpleMiddleware` class in `portal/middleware.py`, which does not match your filename `portal/middleware/MiddleWare.py`.

Comment: I did. But now nothing seems to load at all. Not even syntax errors in my `MiddleWare.py` file are caught.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are referencing `MiddleWare.py` anywhere - your setting references `portal.middleware`.

Comment: Yes, and I was expecting errors that it couldn't find those. This is, I still had an old `.pyc` file still there, which provided the class. (I was experimenting and playing ...). It looks like I have it now.